# n98-magerun.phar not working - PHP Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found

Tags: magento-1.8, php, composer, linux, magerun

I can't execute n98-magerun.phar, I get `PHP Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found`.

I am using PHP 5.5.14 (cli)

Any hints how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I had to install phar by executing `apt-get install php-phar`

Answer (score 2):

Check if the `phar.so` extension is present in your PHP installation. It has to be enabled in your php.ini file.

If it is not, you can either change your php.ini file, or should be able to call n98-magerun like this:

`php -d extension=phar.so n98-magerun.phar`

Comment: How can I enable it?

Comment: ...it is written in my answer: *If it is not, you can either change your php.ini file [...]*

Comment: I know, but the info is missing what I have to add to the php.ini to enable it. How does it work?

Comment: There should be a line `;extension=phar.so`. Remove the semicolon from the beginning, and save the file. If the line is not there, you can add it. If that results in an error, your PHP version has been compiled without that extension - but I have not encountered that so far. If the shell command I added in the answer works, this should not be the case.

Comment: Does not work, I added the line and restarted apache2 but I still get `PHP Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found` and `PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php5/extensions/phar.so'` even if I execute your command

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with your PHP CLI setup. Do `php --version` to find out if you're really using PHP 5.5.14, and `php --ini` to find out if you edited the correct file.

Comment: Thanks to your command I noticed that the module is not installed, even though it should be installed according to http://php.net/manual/de/phar.installation.php
"The Phar extension is bundled with PHP as of PHP version 5.3.0, and enabled by default."

`apt-get install php-phar` solved it.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this : n98-magerun For Magento 1**

1. wget http://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun-latest.phar
2. chmod +x ./n98-magerun.phar
3. ./n98-magerun.phar list

**Description About Db Commands**

https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun-doc/blob/master/docs/languages/en/commands/db.rst

**For Example:**

- BD export Command: ./n98-magerun.phar db:dump -c gzip
- BD import Command: ./n98-magerun.phar db:import db_name.sql
- cache clear Command: ./n98-magerun.phar cache:flush

Comment: Does not work, I get `wget: option requires an argument -- 'O'` and `wget: missing URL`

Comment: answer update can you check @Black
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Comment: I still get the same error `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phar' not found in`